# Здравствуйте, задача получить данные с l76x gps hat на rock pi x по usb, вопрос как это сделать через minicom или любое другое приложение под линухом?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, gps, serial

1. Моя версия ОС 22.04 LTS
2. Вывод команды 'lsusb':

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

'Device 003' это мой l76x gps hat.

3. Вывод команды 'ls -l /dev/ttyS*':

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 74 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS10
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 75 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS11
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 76 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS12
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 77 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS13
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 78 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS14
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 79 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS15
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 80 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS16
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 81 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS17
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 82 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS18
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 83 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS19
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 84 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS20
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 85 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS21
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 86 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS22
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 87 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS23
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 88 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS24
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 89 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS25
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 90 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS26
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 91 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS27
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 92 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS28
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 93 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS29
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 94 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS30
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 95 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS31
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 69 июл 18 20:09 /dev/ttyS5
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 70 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS6
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 71 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS7
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 72 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS8
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 73 июн 27 21:28 /dev/ttyS9
```

4. Вывод команды 'ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*':

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

5. Результат выполнения команды `sudo dmesg | grep -A10 -B10  ttyUSB*`

```
    [    7.700091] pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend
    [    7.712702] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4345C0
    [    7.712719] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4345C0 (003.001.025) build 0000
    [    7.725919] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
    [    7.725944] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd'
    [    7.725951] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
    [    7.746150] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
    [    7.752328] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
    [    7.757350] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
    [    7.771315] cp210x 1-4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
    [    7.775742] usb 1-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
    [    7.938861] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
    [    7.939010] brcmfmac mmc2:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.ROCK Pi-ROCK Pi X.bin failed with error -2
    [    7.950815] brcmfmac mmc2:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.ROCK Pi-ROCK Pi X.txt failed with error -2
    [    7.950887] brcmfmac mmc2:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt failed with error -2
    [    7.961915] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
    [    7.998153] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
    [    8.058588] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
    [    8.062227] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.463:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=434 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.064382] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.463:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=435 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.064404] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.463:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=435 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.079535] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.479:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=439 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.079557] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.479:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=439 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.079568] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.479:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=439 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.092468] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.491:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=436 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.092498] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.491:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=436 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.092510] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.491:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=436 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.092520] audit: type=1400 audit(1658314362.491:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=436 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [    8.204331] SSE version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
    [    8.332600] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input4
    [    8.438579] usb 1-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
    [    8.439721] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
    [    8.439775] cp210x 1-4:1.0: device disconnected
    [    8.546144] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
    [    8.546159] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
    [    8.546167] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: warn: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
    [    8.546187] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
    [    8.587501] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
    [    8.587514] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
    [    8.587521] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: warn: FW ABI is more recent than kernel
    [    8.957779] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
    [    9.199568] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
```

6. Output from 'lsmod | grep usbserial':

```
usbserial              57344  1 cp210x
```

7. Я попробовал получить данные через Cutecom, но там вообще пусто.
8. После ввода команды `sudo dmesg --clear`, а затем `sudo dmesg`, я получил следующее:

```
    [  343.595357] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [  343.746505] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
    [  343.746546] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [  343.746566] usb 1-4: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
    [  343.746582] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
    [  343.746596] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 0001
    [  343.750399] cp210x 1-4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
    [  343.761263] usb 1-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
    [  348.332168] usb 1-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
    [  348.334781] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
    [  348.335052] cp210x 1-4:1.0: device disconnected
```

Пожалуйста, помогите с данной задачей...

Comment: Исправил, буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: `sudo dmesg | grep ttyUSB*` перепиши на `sudo dmesg | grep -A10 -B10  ttyUSB*`

Comment: это ж usb-устройство? тогда отключите его, очистите кольцевой буфер ядра (`$ sudo dmesg --clear`), подключите устройство, и приложите к вопросу всё, что после этого будет записано в буфер (`$ sudo dmesg`).

Comment: символом " ` " с двух сторон

Comment: @eri вывод команды `sudo dmesg | grep -A10 -B10  ttyUSB*`,   `[    7.746150] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[    7.752328] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
[    7.757350] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[    7.771315] cp210x 1-4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[    7.775742] usb 1-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0[    7.938861] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6` это всё, что вместилось

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, прикрепил в вопросе вывод команды `sudo dmesg`

Comment: ну сами посмотрите на приложенный вывод: устройство подключается и тут же отключается. так что ничего вы от него получить не сможете. вот с этим отключением и разбирайтесь. лучше в новом вопросе, более конкретном, и без лишнего мусора.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, подскажите в какую сторону копать и в связи с чем может быть это отключение?

Comment: понятия не имею. задайте лучше новый вопрос, приведя там лишь этот кусок лога (который я у вас запросил). может кто и подскажет ещё что-нибудь дельное.

Comment: вон, кстати, eri в ответе подсказывает дельную мысль.

Answer (score 0):

```
[    8.438579] usb 1-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[    8.439721] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[    8.439775] cp210x 1-4:1.0: device disconnected
```

Вот на этом моменте видно что порт ломает сервис **brltty** - попробуй его вырубить.

Comment: --simulate ?)))

Comment: @Matvey, получилось ли выключить или удалить brltty?